# Related to opentext core Share REST api

Tags: content-management-system, opentext

I want to do CRUD operation of file using REST api on opentext core share instead of uploading file to opentext core share from dashboard. So please let me know if opentext is providing api documentation or there is some other way to do this.

opentext core share dashboard:[opentext core share](https://core.opentext.com/app/#/dashboard)

Comment: Did you get an answer because I am looking for it as wel?

Comment: No I posted on opentext forum but still no reply,